# Sending reports at scheduled times

Tags: windows, batch-file, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to set up automated emailing of a few reports for my company and have a few questions after doing some research into it.

So far I have the emailing portion finished and working of MS-Access where it will send emails containing two reports to whomever. I have also set up a `.bat` file to run the macro automatically and can use task scheduler in order to run the macro while I'm logged in and receive the emails.

The problem is I'm trying to set it up so that it will run overnight bi-weekly. When I test out the task scheduler with the option  "Run whether logged on or not"(which since my account does not have admin privileges, I had to switch into an admin account and give my account log on as batch job rights) and try to run it while being logged out, unfortunately it doesn't work.

I have tried out running both Access directly through the task scheduler as well as through a .bat file. The results from the `.bat` file show that the operation completed successfully, but no emails will go through and as far as I know, the `.bat` program does not properly execute. When I attempt to run access directly through the task scheduler, the error shows that the operator or administrator has refused the request(0x800710E0).

Would I need to be running my account as a local administrator in order for this to work? Or should I try to write a batch file with AT commands to try to schedule this?

This is my first attempt at doing anything with Windows for automated scheduling as I've only ever used the crontab functions within linux. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, as well as any questions that might help my clarify what I'm trying to do here.

Code for the `.bat` file:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\*User*\Documents\Asset List Backup 20191126.accdb" /x SendEmail
```

**Edit:**
Code for the Email:

```
Public Function Sendemail1()
Dim crrntdate As String
Dim ol As Outlook.Application, msg As MailItem, atts As Attachments, strFilePath As String, strFilePath2 As String
Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
crrntdate = Format(DateValue(Now), "mmddyyyy")
strFilePath = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Auto Reports\Office Consumables Report " & crrntdate & ".pdf"
strFilePath2 = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Auto Reports\Field Consumables Report " & crrntdate & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "AutoCountReport", acFormatPDF, strFilePath, False
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "AutoCountFieldReport", acFormatPDF, strFilePath2, False
DoEvents

Set msg = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set atts = msg.Attachments
With msg
    .Subject = "Automatic Report for Office Consumables " & crrntdate
    .Body = "Body text" 'Edited
    .To = "Email" 'Edited
    .CC = ""
    atts.Add strFilePath
    atts.Add strFilePath2
    .Send
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to email through Outlook or CDO?

Comment: I'll edit my original post with the code, but I haven't had any problems with sending emails while logged in.  I'm using the Outlook library reference and CDO as far as I know.  Using the .bat file or running the macro will execute without problem unless I'm logged out, the problem is mainly with Task scheduler.

Comment: Why do you need the batch file at all? You can directly execute the app without using the batch file at all from a scheduled task. Also, does the account running the scheduled task have access to the "C:\Users\*User*\Documents" folder? It's typically only available to that user when they're logged in, and if you're running the scheduled task without being logged in, it's not running as that user.

Comment: Change `start` to `start ""`!

Comment: Also, with no user logged in, you may not have access to a network with which to send the email, and the app won't have access to a user account if you're using Outlook to send the mail (which your code indicates you are, now that you've posted it).

Comment: @KenWhite I have both a task with a .bat file and one without for testing purposes to see which one will run as I'm unable to get it to execute while logged out.  But understandably your point on not having network access while logged out may be the root of the issue.  Since my company has a server running, would it make sense to remotely log into my computer using the server to execute the task then log off remotely?  If so, how would I go about doing that progmatically as I only have experience using SSH/Telnet/RDP manually.  Would using net use work for it?

Comment: No, doing anything from the server to log into your machine won't help. You need to create a user that the scheduled task can use (log in as) in order to execute the task. The user needs to have a) network access in order to be able to send mail; b) an Outlook account that can be used to send the mail; and c) access to the folder where the Access database (.accdb file) is located and any required credentials to execute the app. (The reason I suggested getting rid of the batch file is that it adds an extra level of complexity that isn't needed at all.)

Comment: @Compo  Unfortunately that didn't help the underlying issues, but thank you for pointing out flaws in my code as I'm new to using batch file.  Cheers!

Comment: @Mochida, it's not a flaw, your code wouldn't run at all using that batch file. What it would do is create a window title of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE` and invoke the command `"C:\Users\*User*\Documents\Asset List Backup 20191126.accdb" /x SendEmail`. I'd suggest therefore that my change would be essential, in relation to the overall task.

Comment: @KenWhite I will attempt to do that on Monday when I have some time to set up a user account.  I guess the .bat file is adding in extra complexity but I figured I would give it a shot to test all avenues.  So when setting up the user account, I should probably give it admin access correct?  Additionally, within task scheduler, is the option under the general tab "Run whether user is logged on or not" in combination with "Run with highest privileges" more or less all that's needed to have this run, outside of the other parameters you listed.  I apologize for asking so many questions

Comment: @compo Ahhhh k, sorry I thought it was just a formatting change, my apologies.  Oddly enough it seemed to run with what I had before, just not while logged out.

Comment: No, no. Admin access is not required (and is probably a bad idea). You also don't need *highest privileges*. Don't add creating massive security holes to the issues you're already having. The user should have the minimum rights (including folder access) required to perform the task and nothing else.

Comment: What happens when you run, `"C:\Users\*User*\Documents\Asset List Backup 20191126.accdb" /x SendEmail`, _just like that_, from a Command Prompt?

Comment: @compo It runs my macro and sends an email to the account within the macro

Comment: @KenWhite Okay, I'll give that a shot and see how it goes.  Is there any other options that I should be using other than the "Run whether user is logged on or not" and "Wake the computer to run this task" that might help?

Comment: That's why your incorrect command works, @Mochida, because there's an association for `MsAccess.exe` to open `.accdb` files. _I suppose my implication is, 'at the time your batch file is being run, is that association still the same'?_

Comment: @compo When any of the version of the command(original post, your edit or just the "C:\Users\*User*\Documents\Asset List Backup 20191126.accdb" /x SendEmail) they all seem to function.  I don't think I've changed any of the associations as I have access as the default program to open .accdb files.  Should I take out the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" portion then?  Sorry I'm a bit confused by batch files overall as I've only worked with them once before

Comment: No Mochida, I'd always go with the assumption that everything isn't always right with the system it's running on. Leave it as is with my suggested empty title.

Comment: Per user COM settings are not used when running as admin. ONLY system COM setting.